# geom_qq() labeling each datapoint with the corresponding 'year'

Tags: r

```
library(fpp3)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(readr)

# load 'Fastenal' dataset and convert to tsibble
Fastenal <- read_csv('http://course1.winona.edu/bdeppa/FIN%20335/Datasets/Fastenal%20Sales%20(2004-2013).csv')
Fastenal %>% mutate(YearMonth = yearmonth('2004-01') + 0:119,
                    TotSales = Total.Sales/1000000) %>% 
                    as_tsibble(index = YearMonth) -> Fastenal

# Fit AvSalesPD using SNAIVE model
Fastenal %>% model(SNAIVE(AvSalesPD/1000000)) -> fit

# Plot residual QQ plot, label each data points with corresponding 'Year'
fit %>% augment() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(sample = .resid/1000000)) + 
  geom_qq(aes(label = year(YearMonth), geom = 'text') + geom_qq_line()+ theme_ipsum()
```

I'm trying to draw QQ plot, using 'geom = "text"'.
When I run the above codes, I get error message as below;

'Error: geom_text requires the following missing aesthetics: label'

I couldn't find what I did wrong...-_-;

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that geom_qq does not know how to use the aesthetics you are providing. By specifing `geom = "text"` in the function call, it should be drawing text instead of points. The problem is that there is no text supplied that the `geom_text` can use.

Thus we need to supply the labels. The following code should produce what you asked.

```
library(fpp3)
library(readr)

# load 'Fastenal' dataset and convert to tsibble
Fastenal <- read_csv('http://course1.winona.edu/bdeppa/FIN%20335/Datasets/Fastenal%20Sales%20(2004-2013).csv')
Fastenal %>% mutate(YearMonth = yearmonth('2004-01') + 0:119,
                                        TotSales = Total.Sales/1000000) %>% 
                    as_tsibble(index = YearMonth) -> Fastenal

                # Fit AvSalesPD using SNAIVE model
                Fastenal %>% model(SNAIVE(AvSalesPD/1000000)) -> fit

                # Plot residual QQ plot, label each data points with corresponding 'Year'
fit <- fit %>% augment() 

# here we define the labels to use.
labs <- year(fit$YearMonth)
labs <- labs[!is.na(fit$.resid)]
labs <- labs[order(na.omit(fit$.resid))]  #EDIT: important! sort the labels for QQ-plots

ggplot(fit, aes(sample = .resid/1000000)) +
geom_qq(geom = "text", label = labs, angle = 90, size=1.5) +
geom_qq_line()
```

Note how we are manually creating the labels. We pass to `geom_qq` the same arguments as you passed, but outside the `aes()`.
Since we are passing this information outside `aesthetics`, we have to take care that information in `labs` matches that of the `aesthetics` used.
Indeed,the points that you are using to draw the QQ plot have some missing entries (12). These are omitted, and as a result you have 108 points (not 120) in your resulting plot. This is why we have to make sure that `labs` has one entry for each **non-missing** point in your data (i.e. `.resid` entries different from NA).
If you do not filter NAs in the construction of `labs` you end up with an error and no plot.

The above code produces this plot:
[image]

Comment: It seems the problem is now.. as the labels is provided out side aesthetics, the actual data point and the given text label doesn't match. The points in the lower left are mostly 2009~2010 data points.

I still wonder why 'geom_gg(aes(label = year(YearMonth)), geom = 'text')' this code spit out error message like this: 'Error: geom_text requires the following missing aesthetics: label'

Comment: You are correct! I forgot to sort the labels. I edited the code. Solution is a bit hacky, but it works. I was not able to find more _ggplot idiomatic solutions_. My understanding is that `geom_qq` works differently form other ggplot functions like `geom_points`. Indeed, if you try to specify `x` and `y` `aesthetics` as you would normally do it, it will mess up with your `geom_qq` (see [documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_qq.html)). Another **more elaborated** solution would be to extract the x and y axes created by `geom_qq` and make a new plot from scratch.

Comment: To add to the previous comment, if you use:
`ggplot(fit, aes(sample = .resid/1000000, label = "Hello")) +
geom_qq(geom = "text", angle = 90, size=1.5) `, it works just fine, labelling all data points as "Hello"... I really don't know why it doesn't work passing a column of the data frame or another vector. I tried many things, but always end up implementing the vector label manually as in the code above. Anyway, hope the above helps with your problem :)